# negation of std::integral_constant<bool>

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, type-traits, boost-mpl

Sorry for asking so simple question, but I cannot find the answer easily. Google says nothing interesting about "C++ negation integral_constant" and similar queries.

Is there in C++11 any trait that make `std::true_type` from `std::false_type` and vice versa? In other words, I'd like some more readeble version of

```
std::is_same<my_static_bool, std::false_type>
```

I know of course I can write it myself, but I'd like to use the existing one if there is such.

Comment: What is the problem with doing `!my_static_bool`?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I think `my_static_bool` is an integral constant, so he would have to write `std::integral_constant<bool, !my_static_bool::value>` (intentionally without `::value`) to make it right.

Comment: @ipc `constexpr` `operator!` might make it possible, haven't tried though.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: You can't apply operators on types.

Comment: @ipc: From the test above, it seems that `my_static_bool` can be `std::false_type` (or possibly `std::true_type` I imagine). Other than that, I don't quite understand your comment... `std::integral_constant` has a `constexpr` conversion operator `operator value_type()` that in the case of `std::false_type` yields `false`, which can be used with the *not* to yield a `true` constant expression

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: You can't write `!std::true_type`.

Comment: @ipc: Right... my bad, you can only apply the operator to an object, not to the type :) The alternatives are either `!my_static_bool::value` or `!my_static_bool{}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not, because it's essentially a one-liner and the `<type_traits>` should be as small as possible.

```
template <typename T> using static_not = std::integral_constant<bool, !T::value>;
```

Usage:

```
static_not<my_static_bool>
```

This is the correct way because the standard always says "`false_type` or derived from such", so you can't depend on being equal to `std::false_type`. I usually relax that to "having a constexpr boolean `::value` property" because I don't use tag dispatching.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another way to do it:

```
template <typename T>
using static_not = typename std::conditional<
    T::value,
    std::false_type,
    std::true_type
>::type;
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code uses template metafunction forwarding (i.e. it inherits from `std::integral_constant` with a negated boolean value, this is of course inspired by the [**Boost.MPL**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/not.html) that heavily uses this pattern)

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct logical_not
:
    std::integral_constant<bool, !T::value>
{};

int main()
{
   typedef logical_not<std::false_type>::type T;
   typedef logical_not<std::true_type>::type F;

   static_assert((std::is_same<T, std::true_type>::value), "");
   static_assert((std::is_same<F, std::false_type>::value), "");   
}
```

Output on [LiveWorkSpace](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2Btvxh%240)

Answer (score 1):

The types `true_type` and `false_type` have a nested typedef that refers to themselves, so you can write:

```
std::is_same<my_static_bool::type,std::false_type>::value
```

Depending on the context it might be simpler to just do `!my_static_bool{}`, which is a `constexpr` of value `true` if your type is indeed `std::false_type`.